# How to say that you had some memories, but not anymore using "remember"?

Tags: past-tense

Let's say in the past I knew some information, but now it's forgotten. How to do it with the word "remember"? Can I use "I remembered it when..." for that case?

An example:
-You don't remember the formula.
-I remembered it when I was in a school.
-Whatever, now you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible construct might be "used to remember" as in "I used to remember her face when I was young" or "I used to remember the formula when I was still in school."

Comment: How about without "still"?

Comment: Sure, I added the word "still" to emphasize that the person is not in school anymore, but it is not necessary.